# Security errror while accessing WCF Service thru flex application

Tags: .net, apache-flex, wcf

There is flex app accessing  dot net web service (WCF) . Both are hosted in the same machine(Server). The web service wsdl is accessible via browser. Tried accessing the service thru dot net application it works perfect , but when I try accessing the service using the flex applicationI get a  error .

(FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Security error accessing url" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error")

any solution for this issue ?

Comment: can u give the urls? An SWF `abc.example.com` cannot access wsdl in `xyz.example.com` without a crossdomain.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just running the wcf server it from visual studio it wont work

you need to set up ISS on the machine and set the project up correctly in there.

i had the same problem the other day.